# Logging time spent in X windows

Tags: xorg

How could I log the time spent in different X windows?  This could be useful for getting rid of bad habits.

Answer (score 1):

`xdotool` might help here, assuming that can be installed and your environment supports obtaining necessary details:

```
% xdotool getmouselocation
x:680 y:383 screen:0 window:8388621
% xdotool getwindowpid 8388621
63392
% pstree -p 63392
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+- 63392 jhqdoe xterm
   \-+= 63394 jhqdoe -zsh
     \-+= 63441 jhqdoe pstree -p 63392
       \--- 63442 root ps -axwwo user,pid,ppid,pgid,command
```

You may need `xdotool getwindowfocus` instead of `getmouselocation` should focus follows mouse not be used, but the gist of the script would be to get where the mouse is or what is in focus, try to find out what that is for what you need to log, repeat that search every N seconds (a minute?), various error handling, etc.